# Printing every occurance of a specific JSON key

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I would like to print the value of every occurance in a JSON string with Python.

Here is my JSON:

```
{
    "changed": false,
    "results": [{
            "arch": "x86_64",
            "epoch": "0",
            "name": "nagios-plugins-check_ansible",
            "nevra": "0:nagios-plugins-check_ansible-20170803-4.1.x86_64",
            "release": "4.1",
            "repo": "nagios_plugins",
            "version": "20170803",
            "yumstate": "available"
        },
        {
            "arch": "x86_64",
            "epoch": "0",
            "name": "nagios-plugins-check_memory",
            "nevra": "0:nagios-plugins-check_memory-20170801-19.1.x86_64",
            "release": "19.1",
            "repo": "nagios_plugins",
            "version": "20170801",
            "yumstate": "available"
        },
        {
            "arch": "x86_64",
            "epoch": "0",
            "name": "nagios-plugins-check_radius",
            "nevra": "0:nagios-plugins-check_radius-20170802-3.1.x86_64",
            "release": "3.1",
            "repo": "nagios_plugins",
            "version": "20170802",
            "yumstate": "available"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to print every occurence of the "nevra" key to the console. I have tried:

```
import json, sys

obj=json.load(sys.stdin)

i = 0
while True:
    try:
        print(obj["results"][i]["nevra"])
        i = (i + 1)
    except IndexError:
        exit(0)
```

but this produces:

```
NameError: name 'false' is not defined
```

Comment: Its probably because you have "changed": false. If you changed that to a 1 or a zero instead of true false you wouldnt get the name error.

Comment: The code you post seems to work and doesn't reflect the error you are quoting.

Comment: @quamrana My mistake, removing the last "else" condition will cause the error to appear, had to add it or else the system that the code was running on would become unresponsive

Comment: I still find that your code works and does not produce the error you state.

Comment: Your dictionary has boolean `false` value instead of `False`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use:

```
for result in obj['results']:
    print(result['nevra'])
```

This generates:

```
>>> for result in obj['results']:
...     print(result['nevra'])
... 
0:nagios-plugins-check_ansible-20170803-4.1.x86_64
0:nagios-plugins-check_memory-20170801-19.1.x86_64
0:nagios-plugins-check_radius-20170802-3.1.x86_64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can finish it one line also :

```
nevra = [ v["nevra"] for v in data['results']]
```

Output :

```
['0:nagios-plugins-check_ansible-20170803-4.1.x86_64', '0:nagios-plugins-check_memory-20170801-19.1.x86_64', '0:nagios-plugins-check_radius-20170802-3.1.x86_64']
```

Answer (score 0):

> to print every occurence of the "nevra" key to the console

Discover ***[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/)*** tool:

```
jq -r '.results[] | if has("nevra") then .nevra else empty end' yourjsonfile
```

The output:

```
0:nagios-plugins-check_ansible-20170803-4.1.x86_64
0:nagios-plugins-check_memory-20170801-19.1.x86_64
0:nagios-plugins-check_radius-20170802-3.1.x86_64
```

Comment: This is not in Python

Comment: @AdamChance, as you are working in console, jq would be the best tool for JSON data